# Drawing the front of a cylinder (CALayers)

Tags: ios, calayer, transparent

I'm trying to draw the following shape using CALayers (the end result will be an animatable cylinder). I'm having trouble setting it together. My idea was to draw an ellipse for the bottom part (green), add a rectangle up to the top (blue), and then subtract an ellipse from the top (red). I need this specific shape, as it will be transparent.

[image: Left is the desired shape, right is how I figured to build it.]

I tried creating the shapes using `UIBezierPath`, combine these using a `CGMutablePathRef`, add that to a `CALayer` and then set the fill rule to `kCAFillRuleEvenOdd`.

My initial idea was to the animate the Y-scale of this layer, but I know realize that this will deform the bottom and top.

Any input on how to do this (and it has to be an animatable, using Core Animation solution) is highly appreciated!

Comment: you can position your layers in 3D space in the shape of a cylinder while giving your parent view a perspective sublayer transform

Comment: Having never used anything 3D in iOS before; what framework should I be using? How is this performance-wise? I need the animation every second, or so.

Comment: You use CA. You set the transform property of each layer around the cylinder...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. One question though; how would I create the 'body'? Bend a rectangle (how?) or is there a way to create 3D shapes as well?

Comment: You must approximate a cylinder using many layers. So, you could construct a cylinder with 30 sides or 50 sides, etc.

Comment: Use three layers.  Two ellipses and one rectangle.  position the ellipses based on the z-scale of the rectangle.

Comment: Thank you @HalR. But how would that create the curvature? Note that the ellipses can not overlay the rectangle, as these will be transparent.

Comment: Just draw the top ellipse when in clear mode.   CGContextSetBlendMode( context, kCGBlendModeClear );